# Ubuntu installer to only install selected packages

Tags: package-management, installation, custom-installer

How can I make a custom installer to install only the packages I specify (including proprietary components and drivers) and preconfigure config files like `/etc/network/interfaces` beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [InstallCustomCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization) page has all the information you need to create a custom installer.

However I personally just automate the [install using preeseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/amd64/appendix-preseed.html) instead of customizing a CD. That way I can use whatever vanilla Ubuntu CD and just add my changes on top of it as part of the install process.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but any easy guides to get me started?

Comment: Can I get custom Live session using preseeding? Preseeding sounds like it's limited to manipulating only the packages on the ISO images without the possibility to add extra packages.

Comment: Nope, the LiveCD is an image, you'd need to customize the image so you can't really do stuff to it on boot.